# finding unique rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables:

**Table 1** :

```
Row_Id    SR_NUM
------------------
100       1-12345
101       1-34567
```

**Table 2**:

```
SRA_Id   Value
----------------
100      Test
101      (Blank)
100      (Blank)
100      (Blank)
101      (Blank)
```

When I am creating the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a. SR_NUM,
    b.value
FROM
    Table_1 a,
    Table_2 b
WHERE 
    a.row_id = b.sra_id
```

I am getting 3 records in output (2 for 100 - one with value as 'Test' and another value as (Blank))

I want it to show only 1 record for 100 with value and not the blank one.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Missed Table 2 have multiple rows as

Comment: (blank) and "Test" are different values, thus you get 2 rows for id 100 using distinct. What distinct does is to eliminate duplicates where all the column values are same. 
Your intention is not really clear, in your sample you want "Test" for 100. OK but then what do you want for 101? A (blank) or nothing? What if for 100 there were another row where value was "Test2", then what?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY a.SR_NUM` and choose e.g. the `MAX(b.VALUE)` might be what you want.

```
SELECT a.SR_NUM,
       MAX(b.VALUE) VALUE
       FROM Table_1 a
            INNER JOIN Table_2 b
                       ON a.ROW_ID = b.SRA_ID
       GROUP BY a.SR_NUM;
```

(If `MAX()` gives you the "(Blank)" ones (I assume you mean `NULL`) replace it with `MIN()`.)

Comment: How do you reason he wants max() - or Min()? Maybe then he wants all non-null values.

Comment: I want both null and non null values. Query should give me output with 2 records                                                                                                               SR_NUM  Value                                                                                                       _________________                                                                                  100           Test                                                                                         101            (Blank)

Comment: @Amit J: That's exactly what my (one of them, with either `MAX` or `MIN`) query will produce. When there are only `NULL`s `MAX()` gives `NULL` as well as `MIN()` gives `NULL`. Have you even tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but you can try:

```
SELECT a.SR_NUM, b.value FROM Table_1 as a 
JOIN Table_2 as b ON (a.row_id = b.sra_id AND b.value != "(BLANK)");
```